# Script Editor hiding when telling a different application to close/hide

Tags: applescript, keystroke

Why does the following Applescript hide Script Editor?

```
tell application "Last.fm" to launch
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Last.fm" to keystroke "h" using command down
```

This code I found will hide "Last.Fm", but also hides Script Editor.  Ideally, I want to replace the `keystroke "h"` with a `keystroke "w"` but then I get an error:

`The document can’t be closed while the script is running.`

Why does the script I wrote effect Script Editor?

Comment: On my machine, the name of this application / process is "Last.fm Scrobbler". Could it be that your problems are caused by getting the name wrong? Just a guess...

Comment: @matt I don't think I have the name wrong, because if Last.fm is not running, it does indeed open last.fm ( which is what I desire )

Comment: The application name (for launching) and the process name (for driving with GUI scripting through System Events) are different things. Look in Activity Monitor and you will see that it is called "Last.fm Scrobbler". Would you please just try it and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @matt no difference here.  It does the same thing - except I noticed that it doesn't even hide Last.fm, as it seems to run the hide command before it is running.  I have a gif capture if you'd like to see!

Comment: What if you change "launch" to "activate"? These two commands are not the same; an activate usually gives full focus to the app whereas launch doesn't necessarily bring an app frontmost.

Comment: @CRGreen no difference - Last.fm still opens and appears in front of all of the windows.

Comment: No, I think @CRGreen is right.

Comment: neither of these suggestions, however, answer my question though, which is "why script editor itself has its window hidden/closed when I run that line"

Comment: Because you are asking the wrong question. :) This is AppleScript and GUI scripting - it's weird stuff. You don't need any more "why" than that. Once you accept that, you can just get yourself a working solution and move on.

Comment: @matt heh I can deal with that, I suppose :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Last.fm, so I tried this:

```
tell application "TextEdit" to launch
delay 2
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit" to keystroke "h" using command down
```

And sure enough, it's true, TextEdit was hidden but so was Script Editor.

Then I tried this:

```
tell application "TextEdit" to launch
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
delay 2
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit" to keystroke "h" using command down
```

TextEdit was hidden, but Script Editor was not. So I would guess that this will help in your code too. Having the target app frontmost appears to be crucial (which makes a certain amount of sense, after all).

Comment: Something very interesting - when running this job as cron - it actually hides whatever active window I have open, whenever it is run.  All I want is for the Last.fm app ( or any app ) to run if its not running, and not appear so it doesn't get in the way of anything.  I'm going to remove the hide code and see what happens, because it keeps hiding my windows haha.

Comment: "it actually hides whatever active window I have open, whenever it is run" Not surprising, really. After all, what is GUI scripting? You're just telling the system to act as a ghost user: you are telling it to type Command-H. So whatever Command-H would do at that moment, that is what happens. Well, what does Command-H do? It hides whatever is frontmost.

Comment: it most certainly does make sense.  I ended up changing my code to just show it, and removed the hiding part.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What is the functionality you're trying to achieve here? Is this the whole script? You want last.fm to launch, and then, ideally, to close the window?

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process
```

Doesn't work because it is highly misleading - it will *not* actually direct a keystroke to a particular application, the keystroke goes wherever it would go when it's hit regardless of the "tell process" statement, which is annoying.

I don't use last.fm, but either of these works for me:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    launch
    activate
end tell
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "w" using command down
end tell
```

or

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    launch
    activate
end tell
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    click menu item "Close" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

Note that if you plan to run the script from a key command or the script menu, and don't want it to steal focus to last.fm, you can have it launch, close the window (or hide it), and then return you to the front app when the script was run:

```
set appPath to the path to the frontmost application
tell application "Finder"
    set appName to the name of file appPath
    set appName to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in appName) - 1) of appName
end tell
tell application "TextEdit"
    launch
    activate
end tell
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "w" using command down
end tell
tell application appName to activate
```